# Как правильно называются оборудывание

Tags: сеть, wifi, lan

нужна небольшая помощь в названии устройств. Есть небольшое заведение и необходимо устроить фай вай сеть по всей територии. Провайдер индефецирует клиентов по MAC-адресу, значит настройки приходят автоматом. Желательно такое устройство с 8-10 портами, что-то по типу `Tp-Link TL-SG2008` но как я понял он не может получать настйки, а может и ошибаюсь. Дальше планирую поставить `Tp-Link TP-Link AC50` и поставить 4 точки доступа `Tp-Link EAP110`. Интересует небольшая консультация, все ли я спланировал или необходимо что-то докупить? Интересуют недорогие решения, заказывать все будут через интернет. У нас имеется сеть, постоенная на unifi, но она дорого вышла.

Comment: «астройки приходят автоматом» — как именно и куда приходят? Обычно к интернет-провайдеру подключают в первую очередь роутер, который уже примет настройки от провайдера по DHCP

Comment: @andreymal так и есть. Думал просто что-бы роутер не ставить, а сразу что-то нормально что можно будет в шкаф засунуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите купить свитч, но на такую задачу нужен роутер.

Кроме того, вы выбрали самые дешевые и глупые точки доступа, так что сеть у вас будет работать без роуминга.

Выводы - из триады дешево - просто - качественно, выберите любые два:

- если выкинуть *дешево*, решение вы знаете - это юбиквити
- если убрать *просто*, покупайте микротики и настраивайте `CAPSMAN`
- если проигнорировать *качественно*, можно наколхозить из того что есть - сделать одну из точек роутером, остальные прицепить к ней в качестве клиентов через свитч. Как такой колхоз будет работать? Ну, как-то будет.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. дешевые - да, а почему глупые? Из этого я понял что должно строится по такой цепочке `Роутер (болемение нормальный) -> небольшой хаб на 16 портов(неуправляемый) ` а от хаба кинуть кабель на контроллер вайфай и сами вайфайки?

Comment: Точки глупые потому, что никакого роуминга или работы под управлением контроллера не умеют

Comment: Вот все что вы тут нагородили (роутер, свитч, контроллер точек доступа, источник питания PoE) помещается в один (прописью: **1**) юнит с надписью Микротик на борту, и точки доступа на местах с такой же надписью.